# Sending a cookie value with file download in perl

Tags: perl, cookies, http-headers, submit, download

I've got a submit button on a webpage which performs a file download when clicked.

I'm trying to disable the submit after click (to prevent resubmit while the file is created server-side) then re=enable the submit button when the file is downloaded.

I've almost got it working by following the tutorial below, in short:

- When download is clicked get current timestamp and store it in a
  hidden field
- Send the timestamp with the download request to the server
- Server does the file processing
- Server creates a cookie with the timestamp value sent from the client
  in the original request
- Server sends the cookie to the client along with the file to download
- On the client if the cookie value matches the hidden field timestamp
  the submit is re-enabled

[Detecting file download in browser](http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx)

The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to send the cookie value back to the client with the file download header, if I include set-cookie in the header it breaks the file download process.

Here's my current header, which works:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$file; Content-type: $type\n\n$content
```

If I do this it breaks:

```
Set-Cookie:$cookie; Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$file; Content-type: $type\n\n$content
```

I'm creating a cookie on the server with the timestamp value from the client using:

```
$cookie = CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>'fileDownloadToken',-value=>"$token_value");
```

Does anyone know how I should go about doing this, coding in Perl?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I've fixed it.  Just in case anyone else comes up against this it appeared to be the format of the header, instead of using a single string:

```
print qq(Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$file; Content-type: $type\n\n$content)
```

I used this:

```
print $page->header(
            -'cookie' => "$cookie",
            -'Content-disposition' => "attachment; filename=\"$file\"",
            -'Content-type' => $content
);
```